# Trouble with MAX(col)+1 INSERT into same MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I need two id columns in the same table that create unique values upon insert. Since MySQL allows only one column to auto-increment, I need to do something like max(id)+1 for the other column.

Here's the SQL I expected to work:

```
INSERT INTO invoices (invoiceid)
VALUES ((SELECT MAX(invoiceid)+1 FROM invoices))
```

The select statement works independently, but within my INSERT, it's not allowed. I get the error : You can't specify target table 'invoices' for update in FROM clause

Comment: You are aware that this won't work correctly with multiple transactions?

Comment: Have you tried using a variable? It would mean 2 queries committed as one.http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `INSERT INTO .... SELECT FROM` instead of `INSERT INTO...VALUES()`:

```
INSERT INTO invoices (invoiceid)
SELECT MAX(invoiceid)+1 
FROM invoices
```

My question for you would be why are you not use an `AUTO INCREMENT` field to generate the `invoiceid` value?  That is what it is for, then you will not have to create this when inserting data.

Comment: Still won't work. MySQL won't allow you to select from the table you are inserting into.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name see this demo - it is working on sql fiddle -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/776f5/1

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Then this is apparently not considered a sub-select.

Comment: That worked! Thank you. The reason I can't use auto increment is because I need the row id to auto increment. The row id and invoiceid must be independent for my application.